# Create a dynamic rescheduling GSource in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, glib, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

[GLib's main loop](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.50/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) supports scheduling callback functions for periodic intervals, using [g_timemout_source_new](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.50/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-source-new) and related functions. The callback will repeatedly be called after the scheduled interval, until it returns `false`.

I now want to modify this process with a dynamic interval. Instead of just `true` or `false`, the callback should be able to return a time value that should pass until its next invocation.

Doing this in C is quite straightforward: A new GSource Type can be created, that only differs from the timeout source in its [dispatch function](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/gmain.c#L4660), which then takes into account the return value [when setting the next expiration](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/glib/gmain.c#L4679).

Unfortunately, I am programming an extension for the GNOME Shell, so I'm stuck to JavaScript. The main critical point to porting the above strategy to JavaScript seems to be the equivalent of [the `g_source_new function`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.50/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-new), `new GLib.Source`. First, it requires the length of the struct type to initialize, which would be computed by the `sizeof` operator in C. I do not know how to get this value in JavaScript. In addition, it is an error to attempt the creation of [a GSourceFuncs Struct](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.50/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GSourceFuncs), the second argument to this constructor, which is needed to hold the dispatch function.

```
gjs> new imports.gi.GLib.SourceFuncs()
Error: Unable to construct struct type SourceFuncs since it has no default constructor and cannot be allocated directly
```

How can I create a new GSource in JavaScript?

Comment: I am also open to other solutions, involving the adaptation of an existing source type or [the inclusion of binary components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919457/including-binary-components-in-a-gnome-shell-extension).

Answer (score 0):

`g_source_new()` was not really designed for language bindings and should probably be marked to be skipped when generating bindings for JS or Python.

Including your own private C library, accessed via GObject introspection, as you suggest in your other question, is what I would usually do in an app. However, I have no idea if you can do it for a shell extension.

You should quite easily be able to implement what you want in JS, though. Here's a simple example I wrote from memory that seems like it might do what you want:

```
const Scheduler = new Lang.Class({
    Name: 'Scheduler',
    schedule: function (timeMs, callback, priority=GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT) {
        this._callback = callback;
        this._priority = priority;
        GLib.timeout_add(priority, timeMs, this._onTimeout.bind(this));
    },
    _onTimeout: function (
        let nextTimeoutMs = this._callback();
        this.schedule(nextTimeoutMs, this._callback, this._priority);
        return GLib.SOURCE_REMOVE;
    },
});
```